# Windows 8 Lenovo Laptop pressing random keys at random intervrals

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

On random intervals, my (Windows 8) computer seems to recognize random keystrokes being put into the keyboard without my typing. It essentially starts typing random keys from the qweasd section and then goes into a long e spam, then it goes and presses space, tab etc. etc. etc. Could this be a virus? or could it be that my keyboard is damaged? I have used those keys quite often for gaming, but that's about it... I tried updating all drivers and stuff but nothing works.

Comment: Turn off your laptop, put it like a tent with your laptop screen and keyboard facing down, get a gas duster and blow the corners of the key. If you want to make sure it isn't a virus, enter BIOS/EFI and get into the password field, see if it also phantom type there

Comment: It doesnt show up in the BIOS or a live CD and the sequence is becoming more frequent now with mouse clicks happening frequently as well...if its a virus  or keylogger, its not being detected by my antivirus software (norton 360) or CCcleaner...how can i fix this! :C

Comment: a little late to reply, but it seems the problem was a improper connection b/w the keyboard and the laptop mobo, dusted the s**t out of it and reinserted all of the key connections and poof, worked like a charm, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

A virus could very well be doing this, however I suspect a different player at work. Are you sure that no one is remoting to your computer? Open the Task manager and go to `Users` Are you seeing that someone else is connected? better yet, try [disabling remote desktop](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/remote-desktop-faq)

Answer (score 0):

Another option for anyone reading this to consider is machine over heating.  I have a dell that gets random key strokes and cursor movement after a few minutes of turning on.  When I run a fan towards the intake the problem goes away.  I was able to make the issue a lot rarer by lowering the Intel TDP level and increasing the acoustic level in the power options.